# Need to print the first occurrence of k-size subsequence, but my code prints the last

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

You are given a string my_string and a positive integer k. Write code that prints the first substring of my_string of length k all of whose characters are identical (lowercase and uppercase are different). If none such exists, print an appropriate error message (see Example 4 below). In particular, the latter holds when my_string is empty.

Example: For the input my_string = “abaadddefggg”, k = 3 the output is For length 3, found the substring ddd!
Example: For the input my_string = “abaadddefggg”, k = 9 the output is Didn't find a substring of length 9

this is my attempt:

```
my_string = 'abaadddefggg'
k = 3
s=''
for i in range(len(my_string) - k + 1):
    if my_string[i:i+k] == my_string[i] * k:
        s = my_string[i:i+k]
if len(s) > 0:
    print(f'For length {k}, found the substring {s}!')
else:
    print(f"Didn't find a substring of length {k}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `break`. When you find the first occurrence you need to exit from the `for-loop`. You can do this with `break`. If you don't `break` you continue and maybe find the last occurrence if exists.

```
my_string = 'abaadddefggg'
k = 3
s=''

for i in range(len(my_string) - k + 1):
    if my_string[i:i+k] == my_string[i] * k:
        s = my_string[i:i+k]
        break
        
if len(s) > 0:
    print(f'For length {k}, found the substring {s}!')
else:
    print(f"Didn't find a substring of length {k}")
```

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and also You can write a function and use `return` and then find the first occurrence and `return` result from the `function.`

```
import itertools

def first_occurrence(string, k):
    for key, group in itertools.groupby(string):
        lst_group = list(group)
        if len(lst_group) == k:
            return ''.join(lst_group)
    return ''

my_string = 'abaadddefggg'
k = 3
s = first_occurrence(my_string, k)
if len(s) > 0:
    print(f'For length {k}, found the substring {s}!')
else:
    print(f"Didn't find a substring of length {k}")
```

Comment: Nice.  Thinking about the same use of *groupby* too.  +1.

Comment: Thank you! for some reason when I tried break the first time it didn't work (maybe i placed it wrong..)

Comment: Maybe name the ```a, b``` to ```key, group``` as conventional  way?  just to make it easier to know what's what... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

One alternative approach using an iterator:

```
my_string = 'abaadddefggg'

N= 3

ou = next((my_string[i:i+N] for i in range(len(my_string)-N)
           if len(set(my_string[i:i+N])) == 1), 'no match')
```

Output: `'ddd'`